# Redirect routes not redirecting to the correct routes

Tags: laravel-5

I'm building a dashboard interface in Vue with Vue-router using history mode.  Everything is working fine when you navigate to the individual routes cooresponding to the sections of the dashboard (e.g. '/employees/dashboard/main', '/employees/dashboard/orders/all').  I'm trying to set up some redirects in the web.php file using Route::redirect('/here', '/there').  I want everything to go to my dashboard landing page route: '/employees/dashboard/main'.  Some routes properly redirect and some don't depending on if a '/' is at the end of the URI or not.

'/employees' redirects to '/dashboard/main' (incorrect)

'/employees/' redirects to '/employees/dashboard/main' (correct)

'/employees/dashboard' redirects to '/employees/dashboard/main' (correct)

'/employees/dashboard/' redirects to '/employees/dashboard/dashboard/main' (incorrect)

**web.php** (snippet)

```
//Employee Routes
//below route was also giving the same result but I left here to show that    
//I've also tried it.
//Route::redirect('/employees', '/employees/dashboard/main');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'employees'], function() {
  Route::redirect('', 'dashboard/main', 308);
  Route::redirect('/', 'dashboard/main', 308);
  Route::redirect('/dashboard', 'dashboard/main', 308);

//catch-all route so vue router routes don't throw 404
Route::get('/dashboard/{any}', 'EmployeeController@showDashboard')
  ->where('any', '.*')
  ->name('employee.dashboard');
});
```

**employee-dashboard.js** (snippet)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  routes: [
    {path: '/employees/dashboard/main', component: Main},
    {
      path: '/employees/dashboard/orders',
      component: Orders,
      redirect: '/employees/dashboard/orders/active',
      children: [
        {path: 'all', component: FilteredOrders},
        {path: 'active', component: FilteredOrders},
        {path: 'completed', component: FilteredOrders}
      ]
    }
  ]
});

const dashboard = new Vue({
  el: '#dashboard',
  router
});
```

Then in dashboard.blade.php I have my router-links and router-view set up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:
What's even more strange is when I comment out all of the Route::redirect entries in web.php, run php artisan route:clear, and restart php artisan serve, then go to /employees, it still redirects me to the wrong route (/dashboard/main).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause of the bad redirects.  The browser caches redirects and for some reason will use that rather than the updated redirect route in the routes/web.php file.  To clear this cache in Firefox: Go into the history menu and right click on one of the pages from your laravel project, then click "Forget about this site".  It will now use the updated redirect routes in your routes file.

I've also changed the redirect to: Route::redirect('/employees', '/employees/login'); since I'm using Laravel's Auth scaffolding and have it set up to redirect to the main page of my dashboard after logging in.

Here is where I found this solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox#661767